# Jenkinsfile is failing with error @tmp/durable-df843027/script.sh: line 1: terraform: command not found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to run a terraform commands from Jenkinsfile stage. The code I'm using is as below:

```
node {

    checkout(scm)       
        stage ('Templates Deployment'){
            sh "terraform init"
        }
}
```

This fails with the error as :

```
+terraform init
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Terraform-Code/@tmp/durable-df843027/script.sh: line 1: terraform: command not found
```

Terraform is installed on the Jenkins server. When I execute the *terraform init* command from the server(CLI), it works fine.
But while running it from the Jenkinsfile(console) it's throwing this error.

Can someone please suggest how this error can be resolved? Any help to execute terraform commands via Jenkinsfile is highly appreciated.

Comment: In CLI, which's user did you run `terraform init` ?

Comment: as a root user.

Comment: switch to jenkins user, then check again,

Answer (score 2):

**Configure Terraform**

Go to Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > It will display Terraform on the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the PATH inside the environment block:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        PATH = "/usr/local/bin/:$PATH"
    }
    stages{
        stage("first stage"){
            steps{
                sh "cd /Users/<user>/Terraform/proj1"
                sh "pwd"
                sh "terraform"
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give full path of terraform binary or set PATH before terraform init

`node {

```
checkout(scm)       
    stage ('Templates Deployment'){
        sh """
          PATH=/bin/terraform
          terraform init"
    }
```

}`